# How to have a scheduled task running within an express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

sorry the title isn't too clear I'm not really sure how to phrase what I'm asking for here.. But basically I'm creating a web app which is a list of public game servers. Pretty much everything is set up now except I want for the server to go through the list of servers and ping them to check they're only every 15 minutes.

How can I do this in express? If I use setInterval will the rest of the express server continue to function as normal or would this interfere with express? I'm also concerned if I eventually have lots of servers on the list that this might not be a good solution if the express server has to pause and stop serving webpages every 15 minutes to ping 100s of servers? Is there a better way to go about doing this, I'm also thinking a python app that is run alongside the server could handle this would this be a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: `setInterval` does not interfere with the other server code, excluding lag and setting variables. It's asynchronous.

Comment: But what if the script to ping all the servers takes a long time to complete if I have lots of servers in the database?

Comment: setInterval will not interfere with your existing functionality. If you are looking for alternative have a look https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron

Comment: @imattacus The only problem would be lag, with a decent server this should barely be noticeable.

Comment: I wouldn't ping 100 servers at the same time,. I would do a round robin approach and divide the 15 mins, into 100 or how many server you want to check..  This would mean you only need to check a server every 9 seconds etc, and with Node been asynchronous it's not going to cause any issues / lag CPU usage etc..  I would go as far as saying you could check 1000+ servers every 15 mins without issues.  As that's only checking just under 1 second, and that still leaves node loads of headroom.

Comment: @Keith thanks for that advice! So would perhaps even not having a setInterval be better for this just have a function that is constantly running and updating servers?

Comment: Although, thinking about it more I suppose just because the function is called every 15 minutes doesn't mean it needs to finish in 15 minutes right? So I could just call the function again after 15 minutes. This is just a project anyway definitely doesn't need to be able to handle large numbers of servers, thanks for the help!

Comment: Indeed, and you could do it that way too.  I would even ask you look into Promises, bluebird has a nice map function that has a concurrency option.. You could use this say to check ping 5 servers concurrently, as you wound't want to ping 100 servers at the same time, that might give you problems.